# weblogic11g datasource not releasing the connections to the pool

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, weblogic

We have developed a Java application with the below specifications.

Frameworks: spring,hibernate
Database: oracle
Server: weblogic 11g

Problem here is when we use Weblogic Data Source the connections are not releasing to the pool which is causing Database server RAM consumption completely after some transactions. But when we use basic Data source in the application the connections are releasing immediately after each transaction and there was no RAM consumption at Database server end. How can I use container based data source?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on  the parameters which you have selected while configuring data source for weblogic. Please check the following
1) Do not enable "Pinned to Thread" properties
2) Enable "Inactive connection time out" to appropriate value. It may be possible that you application has leaked connection

Comment: Thanks Jain. As you told we already set Inactive connection time out to 10 and Pinned to Thread is disabled . But still RAM is consuming in DB server and there was Inactive connection present. But as you told if there was leaked connection in application then same problem has to happen with basic data source as well. But its not happen like that and the memory and connections are release properly with apache basic DS. The only change that we did at application is change from weblogic DS to apache DS (this is working fine with out issue). Kindly help us if some of the config missed in weblogic

Comment: Actually, i need to understand in detail. For e.g. RAM consumption on database server should remain constant. Is the issue related to high consumption of SGA/PGA in database? How you are calculating high RAM consumption.  There will be always some connections in database. Check the status of session in database.  Weblogic will always keep some connection open due to "Min connection" property. Additionally, weblogic will always keep polling database. However, these cannot be reason for high memory. You need to analyse all the db session when memory consumption is high